Carpetas duplicadas anidadas proyecto maven en eclipse
No sé qué hice pero terminé con carpetas duplicadas y anidadas.
En el folder en la pc están bien ordenadas pero en eclipse salen así. Borré una carpeta del proyecto desde el disco duro. Cuando pongo maven update project me dice que no puede anidar porque falta una clase que eliminé manualmente desde eclipse. Probé con mvn clean y siguen apareciendo. También cuando hago mvn package no muestra los últimos cambios en el html. Hice un cambio de versión con mvn set new version. Pero los últimos cambios al html no se reflejan en el war. Hace poco tenía problemas para compilar porque faltaba un tld en un jar. Saqué la dependencia del pom y ya compila. La dependencia esspring security.

Puedes hacer maven clean,  y clean verify? Luego has maven install.

No funcionó. Tuve que crear otro workspace e importar un war de hace unas semanas de este proyecto. Estoy recreando la estructura de folders y poner los archivos en su sitio. Si no funciona tendré que crear un proyecto nuevo y copiar los archivos manualmente.

No puedes solo importar el proyecto más reciente ? Yo abro eclipse, y cargo los proyectos que voy guardando día a dia. (Si, saco un respaldo a diario o cuando hay un estable)

Recrear la estructura de carpetas manualmente me resolvió el problema.
